# Users who constantly ask questions without sufficient information

Tags: discussion

I am posting this, in reference to [this question](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/6432/i-want-a-cost-effective-replacement-for-my-cpu/6436?noredirect=1#comment10144_6436).

I have seen several questions from this user that don't quite give enough information, and when comments are left asking for more information, OP hardly ever comes back to that post.

There are already a LOT of on hold questions...so how do users who repeatedly ask questions that cannot be answered, due to insufficient information get dealt with?

Comment: Heads-up: please don't go starting tangential conversations with folks here on ancient answers on MSE... I get notified of every response, and it's *very* unlikely to be relevant to the answer.

Comment: @Shog9  Very sorry.  Just......got very irritated and reacted irrationally >.<

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We've noticed this pattern too, and have been addressing it with the user directly. There's not much more I can say about that, unfortunately.

In general, this kind of pattern usually results in a moderator engaging the user concerned in private and pointing them towards useful resources, while encouraging them to make more of an effort in future postings. If it's not addressed, this behaviour *can* eventually lead to a suspension, but that isn't something that gets done for just one or two bad questions.

There are also automatic quality blocks in place. The details of these are kept secret, but it works out that if your history of asking questions is bad, you will be blocked from asking questions for a period of time.